# ChartJS - how to config Scales?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js, fiddle

I am creating a website about Bitcoins and using some interactive Charts from ChartJS.

Until now the scales in the Charts are changing with the data. But I think to compare the differencesbetween the years I would like them to not change and stay the same.
So the scale sould be always from 0 - 110.

I already tried to do this but it does't work:
The trick with the max and min...

```
scales:{
  r: {
    ticks: {       
      beginAtZero: true,
      min: 150,       
      max: 150,     
      stepSize: 10,
```

If somebody could help me I would be really greatfull!

Fiddle in the comment.

Cheers!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VS6Cwo3Bh2

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain anything.  From the code fragment in your post I can see that the `min` and `max` options should belong to the axis, not the ticks (so outside of the ticks object) and be different: `options:{scales:{r:{min:0, max: 100, ticks:{.....`

Comment: Omg thanks!!! Now it works! When somebody is watching on a code for too long haha....